# Clickhouse return error when trying to select from Postgres with named collection

Tags: postgresql, clickhouse

I'm trying to query:

`select * from postgresql(postgres, table = 'some_table', database = 'some_database');`

Then I get the error:

`Code: 670. DB::Exception: A named collection 'postgres' already exists. (NAMED_COLLECTION_ALREADY_EXISTS) (version 23.3.5.9 (official build))`

I have a postgres collection in which I store connection data. In this request I am not trying to recreate it, but only perform a select.

For example, when creating a dictionary that takes data from postgres, the collection works as expected when using the NAME keyword